# Word fields - IF statement returns false when it's true

Tags: microsoft-word

So I'd like to use word fields to hide some page numbers. But it seems to not work even with the simplest condition.

My formula in the footer is as follows:

`{IF {PAGE} = "1" "TRUE" "FALSE"   \* MERGEFORMAT }`

However, it gives me a FALSE on every Odd page, where as far as I'm concerned it should be TRUE on the first one.

Comment: The field you show will give a result of "TRUE" on any page with a **formatted page number** of 1. The page number need not be displayed but should show up in your status bar. Try using "{PAGE}" instead. The field delimiters for [PAGE} must be inserted as a pair by Word, they cannot be typed.

Comment: If you care to post a sample document with the problem on DropBox or OneDrive and post a view link in your question, people can probably point out where the problem is. Remove any confidential or proprietary information.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply, however I can't do it right now coz this pic is in my school. It is word 2007 maybe this is the case?  It acts weird, I also tried {IF {PAGE} = {PAGE}"TRUE" "FALSE"   \* MERGEFORMAT } which is always true, and indeed it gave true on every page. However in case above it acts like the first page wouldn't be the first, or like it has problem with translate condition = "1" properly.

Comment: Page numbers and calculation fields have been the same since Word 97 at least. See http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers